# Can't get CI autocomplete from DB to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, mysqli, jquery-ui-autocomplete, codeigniter-3

I recently put my hands on CI and still learning.

My controller:

```
public function test() {
    $keyword=$this->input->post('search[1]');
    $data=$this->hbc_model->search_autocomplete($keyword);        
    //echo json_encode($data);

    $this->load->view('headfoot/test-header-main');
    $this->load->view('test');
    $this->load->view('headfoot/test-footer-main');
}
```

Model:

```
function search_autocomplete($search_term){
    $this->db->select('v_city_name'); 
    $this->db->like('v_city_name', $search_term);
    $response = $this->db->get('vbc_city')->result_array();
    // var_dump($response);
    return $response;
}
```

And view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#main-search" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'hbc_Model/search_autocomplete'
    });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="main-search" name="search[1]" size="20" />
</body>
```

When I uncomment vardump from model or even echo json response from controller, It displays city name all over the page from data base but doesn't work when used as autocomplete.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `.autocomplete()` function is part of jQueryUI, so I added those tags to your question.  Your problem is likely JavaScript, so you'll have to look for errors in the browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

autocomplete expects a [proper formatted](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) source data:
I would proceed like that:

```
 $response = $this->db->get('vbc_city')->result_array();
 $outputString="";
foreach ($response as $city)
$outputString.="'".$city['v_city_name']."',";

print "[".substr(SoutputString,0,-1)."]";
die; // or else the page html will be printed too!
```